Prisma: after npx prisma migrate --name dev
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:1234@localhost:5432/dev?schema=public"
but got this error blow
PS C:\Users\BADELIC\Documents\web projects\prisma-coding> npx prisma migrate dev --name init Environment variables loaded from .env Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "dev", schema "public" at "localhost:5432"  Error: P1000: Authentication failed agai

Please edit your typos and formatting, and add the full error message.
